# User inputted CSV files into Leaflet to display markers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I have created a map that currently pulls data from a csv file located inside the project folder so that it can take the data and create markers on the map. While this works, data is constantly being inputted into the csv file forcing the user to have to go into the vscode platform to manually add the data. I would ideally like for the project to just automatically update the new markers as it's added into the csv file. I'm not sure how possible this it, though, and so, if it's not, can someone help offer a solution on how the user can input the file on the map itself? I know there is a file input plug in but it's not for CSV files. Additionally, I have tried creating file input buttons but I'm not sure how to make it so that my map is still there. Any help is greatly appreciated it!

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>leaflet-map-csv</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css" />

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>


  <!-- PLUG INS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup-src.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>

  <script>


    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [34.098907, -118.327759], // where the map zooms in to
      zoom: 9 // can zoom from 0-18
    });


    //these are the map layers. this can be changed from choosing tiles from a website like: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/
    var light = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.'
    });

    var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      maxZoom: 20,
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    });


    //this just create sthe link from the layer titles to the variable
    var baseLayers = {
      "Carto Light Basemap": light,
      "Stamen Terrain Basemap": terrain,
      "Satellite Basemap": googleSat
    };


    //THIS IS THE SEARCH FUNCTION
    var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder()
      .on('markgeocode', function (event) {
        var center = event.geocode.center;
        L.marker(center).addTo(map);
        map.setView(center, 13);
        //L.circle(center, 900).addTo(map);  this creates a radius everytime you search
      })
      .addTo(map);



    //this creates the toolbar to be able to draw on the map
    var drawnFeatures = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnFeatures);

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
      edit:
      {
        featureGroup: drawnFeatures,
        remove: true
      },
      draw: {
        polygon:
        {
          shapeOptions:
          {
            color: 'red'
          }
        },
        polyline:
        {
          shapeOptions:
          {
            color: 'green'
          }
        },
        rect:
        {
          shapeOptions:
          {
            color: 'purple'
          }
        },
        circle:
        {
          shapeOptions:
          {
            color: 'blue'
          }
        },
        marker: false // follow this format if you don't want a certain shape
      }
    });

    map.addControl(drawControl);


    //this allows the drawings to be created, saved, and edited 
    map.on("draw:created", function (e) {
      var type = e.layerType;
      var layer = e.layer;
      drawnFeatures.addLayer(layer);
    });

    map.on("draw:edited", function (e) {
      var layers = e.layers;
      layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      });
    });
    var controlLayers = L.control.layers(baseLayers);

    var engineerLayers = {}; // Create an object to hold the engineer marker cluster groups



    
    //this retrieves the file
    $.get('\practice.csv', function (csvString) {
      var data = Papa.parse(csvString, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true
      }).data;
      var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();

      for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var engineer = row.Engineer;

        if (!(engineer in engineerLayers)) {
          // Each overlay that should actually be a part of MCG
          // should be made as a Subgroup, with the MCG as their parent
          engineerLayers[engineer] = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup, []);

          controlLayers.addOverlay(engineerLayers[engineer], engineer);
        }

        var marker = L.circleMarker([row.Latitude, row.Longitude], {
          radius: 10,
          stroke: true,
          color: getColor(engineer),
          opacity: 1,
          weight: 1,
          fill: true,
          fillColor: getColor(engineer),
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        }).bindPopup('Plan File: ' + row.PFN + '</br>' + 'Engineer: ' + row.Engineer + '</br>' + ' Date Received: ' + row.Date_Received + '</br>' + 'Status: ' + row.Status);

        // Add the marker only to its overlay
        marker.addTo(engineerLayers[engineer]);
      }

      map.addLayer(parentGroup);
      controlLayers.addTo(map);

    });




    // Must change these if engineers ever change
    function getColor(engineer) {
      switch (engineer) {
        case 'Mike':
          return 'green';
        case 'Salar':
          return 'blue';
        case 'Diego':
          return 'purple';
        case 'Saul':
          return 'orange';
        case 'Chan':
          return 'red';
        default:
          return 'black';
      }
    }

//****IF YOU ARE GETTING AN UNDEFINED LAYER, MAKE SURE TO GET RID OF ANY EXTRA SPACE IN THE CSV FILE 

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```